# Inclusion of Rings after Localization

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

Let $\phi:A \to B $ an injective finite ring map between noetherian integral domains $A,B$. Let $ C \subset B$ a subring of $B$ and assume that there exist a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subset A$ , such that for the induced map on localizations $\phi_p:A_{\mathfrak{p} } \to B_{\mathfrak{p} }:= B \otimes_A A_{\mathfrak{p} }$ the ring $\widetilde{C}_{\mathfrak{p} }$ - which we *define* as subring of $ B_{\mathfrak{p} }$ generated by $ C$ - is contained in the image $\phi_p(A_{\mathfrak{p}})$.

Question: Does then always exist a $ t \in A- \mathfrak{p}$ with $\phi(t) \in C $ such that $C_t$ - that means $C$ localized at $t$ - is contained in the image of $A_t$ under $\phi$?

The problem: even if the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ is finitely generated since the ring A is noetherian, this not neccessary holds for the multiplicative system  $ A- \mathfrak{p}$, so I see no hint how to construct the $ t$.

*Rmk #1:* the finiteness assumpion on $ \phi$ is neccessary, i.e. that $B$ is finite A-module, otherwise there is an obvious counterexample: let $ \phi$ the localization $A \to A_{\mathfrak{p} } =: B$ and let $C=B$.

*Rmk #2:* If the question is still too broad or the answer is negative, then one could also ask a 'baby' version of the problem by *additionally* assuming that $C$ is morevover a $A$- algebra. In this case we may recognize $\widetilde{C}_{\mathfrak{p} }$ as  $C_{\mathfrak{p} }=C \otimes_A A_{\mathfrak{p} }$.

Comment: Are you assuming that $C$ contains the image of $\phi$?  (If not, what do you mean by $C_{\mathfrak{p}}$?)

Comment: @EricWofsey: no, I not neccessarily assumed that that the image of $A$ in contained in $C$. By $ C_{\mathfrak{p} } $ I mean $B_{\mathfrak{p} }:= B \otimes_A A_{\mathfrak{p} }$.

Comment: But I noticed another problem: if $\phi$ is as arbitrary as I stated it in the question, there is an obvious counterexample: let $ \phi$ the localization $A \to A_{\mathfrak{p} } $, with $B=C = A_{\mathfrak{p} } $. I should add additional assumption that $ \phi$ is finite, i.e. that $B$ is finite A-module! I updated this in the question

Comment: $C$ is not in general an $A$-module (so you can't form the tensor product $C\otimes_A A_\mathfrak{p}$), because it might not be stable under multiplication by elements of $\phi(A)$ in your setting (e.g. if $\phi$ is an isomorphism and $C$ is a strict subring containing $1$). Do you maybe mean that $C_\mathfrak{p}$ is the subring of $B_\mathfrak{p}$ generated by $C$?

Comment: @imtrying46: thanks, that's a good point I not took into account when preparing the question. I think the problem should in that can separated in two subcases: one where $C$ is an $A$-algebra and second where $C $ is just a subring of $B$ with additional property that the subring of $B_{\mathfrak{p} }$ generated by $C$ - lets take it as definition of $C_{\mathfrak{p} }$ as you suggested. I should add it in the question

Comment: hope it's a bit clearer now